# Disqus API: How to get recent upvotes across all posts?

Tags: api, disqus

I am the founder of an educational site + app that uses Disqus for commenting.

Recently we have had a spate of spammers upvoting random posts. The upvote causes an email to be generated to the author of the original post, and the upvoter's name is also visible when you hover over the number of votes. The upvoter's display name is usually something like "(Heart) See Bio (Heart)" and the bio contains a link to a porn site, etc. Sometimes the display name is more explicit.

Since the spammer is not actually leaving comments but simply voting on existing comments, the existing spam countermeasures do not catch this. If the spammer votes on a recent post, a moderator might notice, but if they vote on an old post, it would probably go undetected (except to the victim who receives an email notification, and any users who happen to view the upvoter list).

**Is there any way to see a list of all recent upvotes, across all posts on a forum, so that we can manually moderate?** I've looked through the methods in the Disqus API, but I don't see anything. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For what it's worth, you can flag the profile as a spammer or inappropriate profile.

Comment: Thank you, @Mary. Unfortunately, flagging the profile does not remove the upvote or prevent other users from seeing it unless Disqus takes action.

I am happy to say that as of yesterday, it seems Disqus has implemented some changes to remove this upvote spam. Thanks again!